# Show that Frac($R$) is algebraic over $K(\beta_{1},...,\beta_{d})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $R$ be a finitely generated $K$-algebra without zero divisors. Let $\beta_{1},...,\beta_{d}\in R$. If $R$ is integral over $K[\beta_{1},...\beta_{d}]$, then I want to show Frac($R$) is algebraic over $K(\beta_{1},...,\beta_{d})$.

I'm stuck on defining the polynomial that $f(\frac{a}{b})=0$ for $a,b\in R$, can anybody help?

Comment: A remark: if $R$ is finitely generated without zero divisors, for each nonzero $r \in R$ the map $L_r \colon x \in R \mapsto rx \in R$ is $k$-linear and injective. By the dimension hypothesis, it must also be surjective. Hence there exists $s$ for which $rs = 1$. This proves that $R$ was a field to begin with, no need to consider its fraction field. This is essentially the same argument that proves that a finite domain is a field :)

Comment: (cont.) also, this is a particular instance of a more general phenomenon, that localizations go well with integral extensions. Iirc Atiyah-Macdonald covers this pretty extensively (but in a very succinct way)

Comment: Isn't pretty clear that if $S\subset R$ is an integral extension of integral domains then the extension of their field of fractions is algebraic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a polynomial $f= a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + x^n$ with $a_i = p_i/q_i$ and $p_i,q_i \in K[\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n]$ for which

$$
a_0 + a_1 (a/b) + \ldots + a_{n-1}(a/b)^{n-1} + (a/b)^n = 0.
$$

Clearing denominators - i.e. multiplying by $b^n \prod_i q_i$ -  this means precisely that

$$
b^np_0 + p_1b^{n-1}a + \ldots + p_{n-1}b a^{n-1} + a^n = 0.
$$

The "precisely" uses that we can go back, since $R$ has no zero divisors. We have an integral equation

$$
c_0 + \ldots + c_{n-1}a^{n-1}+a^n = 0
$$

with each $c_j \in K[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_r]$ by hypothesis, so we would like to define $p_i = c_i/b^{n-i}$. This in turn shows that $a/b$ is algebraic over $K(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n,b) = K(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)(b)$. But $b$ is integral over $K[\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n]$ hence algebraic over $K(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n)$ and so the result follows by transitivity.